# JPA - Postgres - How to get Results from table using Distinct and Group By

Tags: postgresql, jpa, group-by, distinct

Let's assume I had a **user** table / entity object that looks like this:

```
user
-------
user_id (long)
person_name (String)
employee_type (String)
age (integer)
```

Given a list of user_ids,  I want to write a JPQL query that will return the OLDEST user of each distinct "employee_type". Is it possible to do this?

Comment: How do you want to handle ties (more than one oldest user for a given `employee_type`), should they occur?  General advice: Get the raw SQL query down, and then worry about JPA.  IMO the former is much harder than the latter.

Comment: I don't really need to worry about ties. If there are two users with the same age in the same employee type, returning either one will be sufficient to meet the requirement.

Comment: I attempted an answer below, and if it has issues I will try to work with you to correct it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll try it out and get back to you shortly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `EXISTS` subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user u WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 'found'
    FROM user t
    WHERE t.employee_type = u.employee_type
    GROUP BY t.employee_type
    HAVING MAX(t.age) = u.age
)
```

Comment: Working through this. Something about the max is filtering out more results than it should. Trying to figure this out still...

Answer (score 0):

Let's try

```
Select u from user u
 where u.userId in (:userId)
   and u.age = (
      select max(u1.age) from user u1 
                         where u1.userId in (:userId)
                           and u1.userType = u.userType 
)
```